# How to sort mixed-type sequences (e.g. with numbers and strings) in python3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

When migrating from python2 to python3 I noticed that it is not possible anymore to sort mixed-type sequences in python3.

```
# Python2.7:
sorted(['foo', 'bar', 10, 200, 3])     
# => [3, 10, 200, 'bar', 'foo']

# Python3.6
sorted(['foo', 'bar', 10, 200, 3])
# => TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

**Question 1**. Is there a way to switch back to the old behaviour? This was so useful for my needs. In particular, the following doesn't work for me because the numerical ordering is wrong:

```
# Python2/3
sorted(map(str,['foo', 'bar', 10, 200, 3]))
# => ['10', '200', '3', 'bar', 'foo']
```

This is such a big change in the language specs with the potential of breaking lots of stuff. **Question 2**: What was the rational behind changing this behaviour?

I understand that it is problematic to compare numbers with strings or other objects in general. The old behaviour was useful, however, to achieve a lexicographical ordering that respects numerical values.

Comment: Take a look at [`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) parameter

Comment: @Aran-Fey I reopened the question because answers in that duplicate haven't answered OP's questions completely. Please let me now if you could find a proper duplicate, I couldn't find any.

Comment: @Kasramvd Ah, you're referring to the *"switch back to the old behaviour"* part? Fair enough. Though the answer will either be *"no"* or *"yes, by overriding `builtins.sort`"*.

Comment: Basically it's not important how Python-2 compared different types together but it's very likely that they were compared by the actual name of the types. (int and float as float, dictionary as dict, etc.) And the reason that why they removed this behavior was that sorting a heterogeneous list no longer makes sense – all the elements must be comparable to each other. https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Comment: @Kasramvd How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575183/how-can-i-get-2-x-like-sorting-behaviour-in-python-3-x)?

Comment: Thanks, @Aran-Fey. I didn't stumble upon this post when searching for an answer myself. My post essentially is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Can I ask do you know how exactly Python 2 sorting behaviour worked? (it is not trivial: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26652245/6260170) and why/when do you find it useful?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098443) post for a real-world problem where this change matters.