# Arbitrary but deterministic sort a list of incompatible types

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following lists of pairs:

```py
test1 = [["A", 1],["A", 4], ["D", "Yes"], ["G", 12], ["B", True], ["H", "No"], ["G", 54], ["Z", 412.41]]
test2 = [["D", "Yes"], ["B", True], ["Z", 412.41], ["A", 4], ["G", 12], ["A", 1], ["G", 54], ["H", "No"]]
```

I want to be able to sort each list into a deterministic order. I don't care about the precise order, but if I sort two identical lists, then I want them to end up in the same order.

I tried:

```py
test1.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
test2.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

But I got the error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

How can I consistently sort a list that contains elements of incompatible types, such as str, bool, int, float?

Comment: What should the result be? What is the rule that tells you how to compare the sub-lists - what order do you want them in, according to what logic, and why? What *problem do you hope to solve* by sorting in this way?

Comment: don't call lists list - that hides the list() build in

Comment: I strongly recommend **not** to call a list `list`. `list` is already the name of builtin class `list` in python. Naming a particular list  `list` is confusing and might actually cause unexpected consequences.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The problem is that I expect to receive 2 lists with the identical lists inside them and I want to compare them, but the order might be mixed up. So before comparing, I want to make sure they are in the same order.

Comment: So any consistent ordering would work, then? The given answer is more or less what I would have proposed, then, yes.

Comment: It's possible that using just `lambda x: repr(x[1])` would work too

Comment: Very similar question: [How can I get 2.x-like sorting behaviour in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575183/how-can-i-get-2-x-like-sorting-behaviour-in-python-3-x)

Comment: Note that if all you want is to test for equality, you could use `collections.Counter` instead of sorting: `from collections import Counter; if (Counter(test1) == Counter(test2)): ...`. Although you'd have to convert your lists to lists of tuples rather than lists of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```py
list_1.sort(key=lambda x: (repr(type(x[1])), x[1]))

print(list_1)
# [['B', True], ['Z', 412.41], ['A', 1], ['A', 4], ['G', 12], ['G', 54], ['H', 'No'], ['D', 'Yes']]
```

This will group together the elements which have the same type for their second element. The actual values of `x[1]` will only be compared when the types differ, so you won't have a `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of something and something else`.

Note how `412.41` was isolated from the other numbers, because it is a `float`, whereas the other numbers are `int`.